# How to redirect a URL in Nginx

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

I need to redirect every http://test.com request to http://www.test.com. How can this be done.

In the server block I tried adding

```
rewrite ^/(.*) http://www.test.com/$1 permanent;
```

but in browser it says

> The page isn't redirecting properly
>
> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

My server block looks like

```
 server {
            listen       80;
            server_name  test.com;
            client_max_body_size   10M;
            client_body_buffer_size   128k;

            root       /home/test/test/public;
            passenger_enabled on;
            rails_env production;

            #rewrite ^/(.*) http://www.test.com/$1 permanent;
            #rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://www.test.com$1;

            error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
                    root   html;
            }
    }
```

Comment: The official documentation is at: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html

Answer (score 298, accepted):

Best way to do what you want is to add another server block:

```
server {
        #implemented by default, change if you need different ip or port
        #listen *:80 | *:8000;
        server_name test.com;
        return 301 $scheme://www.test.com$request_uri;
}
```

And edit your main server block server_name variable as following:

```
server_name  www.test.com;
```

*Important*: New `server` block is the right way to do this, [`if` is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/). You must use locations and servers instead of `if` if it's possible. `Rewrite` is sometimes [evil too](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#taxing-rewrites), so replaced it with `return`.

Comment: You could also end that server block with `return 301 http://wwww.test.com$request_uri;` instead of the rewrite.

Comment: ditto @RCCola on using `return` instead of `rewrite`. See [docs](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Taxing_Rewrites)

Comment: Question, how should the server blocks be ordered? the `redirect` then the `main server` block or `main server` block then the `redirect`?
Because I have the same problem, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35451929/nginx-redirecting-non-www-to-www-with-request-uri-does-not-work

Comment: Nginx config in mentioned question is correct, order does not matter.

Comment: Just a quick warning:  Watch out for the `301` redirect vs the `302`.  You could be stuck with a cached permanent redirect, which makes it very troublesome to change your settings for clients that have already accessed a URL.  (I know the OP asked for a `301`, but be sure that's really what you want.)

Answer (score 22):

This is the top hit on Google for "nginx redirect".  If you got here just wanting to redirect a single location:

```
location = /content/unique-page-name {
  return 301 /new-name/unique-page-name;
}
```

Answer (score 18):

Similar to another answer here, but change the http in the rewrite to to $scheme like so:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name test.com;
        rewrite     ^ $scheme://www.test.com$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

And edit your main server block server_name variable as following:

```
server_name  www.test.com;
```

I had to do this to redirect www.test.com to test.com.

Answer (score 10):

First make sure you have installed Nginx with the HTTP rewrite module. To install this we need to have pcre-library

[How to install pcre library](http://www.asep.us/2011/05/30/nginx-instalation-pcre-library-not-found/)

If the above mentioned are done or if you already have them, then just add the below code in your nginx server block

```
  if ($host !~* ^www\.) {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.$host$1 permanent;
  }
```

To remove www from every request you can use

```
  if ($host = 'www.your_domain.com' ) {
   rewrite  ^/(.*)$  http://your_domain.com/$1  permanent;
  }
```

so your server block will look like

```
  server {
            listen       80;
            server_name  test.com;
            if ($host !~* ^www\.) {
                    rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.$host$1 permanent;
            }
            client_max_body_size   10M;
            client_body_buffer_size   128k;

            root       /home/test/test/public;
            passenger_enabled on;
            rails_env production;

            error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
                    root   html;
            }
    }
```