# Nginx Rewrite all http request to www

Tags: nginx

My question is similar to one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294481/how-to-redirect-a-url-in-nginx) . But in my case i am using Godaddy public domain name, which points to a public address and routed to my server which have fixed private ip address (192.168.0.145).If i give server name as domain.com in nginx.conf, nothing works. But if i give localdomain or server private ip it works even if i browse to http://domain.com. I even try adding the domain name to my host fail [127.0.0.1 domain_name] but no luck. I searched through the web but i never seen any one placing private ip or localdomain in the nginx.conf instead of domain address. I really need to redirect all http://domain.name to http://www.domain.com, but since i cannot place my domain name i couldn't find a solution to it. Am i missing something obvious?

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 192.168.0.145;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a tricky solution, you define 2 servers, and the non-www redirects to www

```
server{
    server_name domain.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.domain.com$request_uri
}
server{
    server_name www.domain.com;
    #the rest of your normal config goes here
}
```

all non-www will match server#1 and will be directed to a format that matches server#2

Answer (score 0):

In your server section

```
server_name www.domain.com domain.com 192.168.0.145;

if ($host !~* ^www\.domain\.com$ ) {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: i tried with that, i can see it is forwarding to www.domain.com and then i get page not found error.

Comment: Do you have DNS record for www.domain.com?

Comment: that was the issue, it is fixed now