# How to redirect from www.mysite.com to mysite.com on Nginx?

Tags: nginx, webserver

I have a domain mysite.com and the subdomain www.mystite.com.

I want that all visitors coming to www.mystite.com automatically redirect to mysite.com.

How do I do that?

Comment: Use a proper rewrite rule. What have you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer on there [Nginx Rewrite all http request to www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393056/nginx-rewrite-all-http-request-to-www)
Your case is the opposite, so you'll swap the servers.