# Rails - forward all requests without subdomain to a subdomain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

How do you forward all requests without subdomain to a subdomain?

I want all domain.com requests to go to 
api.domain.com

it's for an angular app which calls get "/resources" etc.  so api.domain.com/resources works but domain.com/resources does not

rails 4

Comment: This could be done in you HTTP Server http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294481/how-to-redirect-a-url-in-nginx

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't know how to get to the server block.  also, this would need to be done in rails, not a server so it can be passed on git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in application controller as a before_action

```
    unless request.url.to_s.include? 'api'
        redirect_to subdomain: 'api' and return
    end
```