# nginx how do I redirect a url to a specific page

Tags: nginx

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294481/how-to-redirect-a-url-in-nginx) which describes how to redirect a url in nginx, as shown below

```
# main server block for www.test.com
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.test.com;
    ...
}

# redirect test.com to www.test.com
server {
        server_name test.com;
        return 301 $scheme://www.test.com$request_uri;
}
```

What I need to do is redirect a set of individual pages, so was wondering how to do this

e.g. `test.com\index` , `test.com\home` , `test.com\main` to **`test.com\index.php`**

Then I have some other pages to simply redirect simply to the .php extension

e.g. `test.com\about` to **`\test.com\about.php`**

e.g. `test.com\contact` to **`\test.com\contact.php`**

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer... assuming the following server block for `test.com`

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.test.com;
    ...
}
```

Add the appropriate regex location path, and `rewrite` or `return` to the redirect url.

for **`test.com\index` , `test.com\home` , `test.com\main` to `test.com\index.php`**

```
location ~ ^/(index|home|main) {
    rewrite ^/.* http://$server_name/index.php permanent;
}
```

for **`test.com\about` to `\test.com\about.php`**

```
location /about {
    rewrite ^/.* http://$server_name/about.php permanent;
}
```