# How do I redirect example.com to example.com/#/ using nginx?

Tags: angularjs, nginx, angular-ui-router

I am using Angular Ui-Router in my web app. Right now I have to use `example.com/#/` to access this. How do I redirect users from `example.com` to `example.com/#/` in Nginx?

Comment: The solution is to use two server block in your nginx config file  [like this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294481/how-to-redirect-a-url-in-nginx

Answer (score 0):

I think that should be purely client-side.
Your webserver will serve the user `index.html` which bootstraps the Angular application.
In your application, you'll have to configure a redirect from "" and "/" to your desired route.

This example below will redirect the user from `example.com` to `example.com/#/home`.

```
  angular
    .module('home', ['ui.router'])
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $urlRouterProvider.when('', '/home');
      $urlRouterProvider.when('/', '/home');
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a bundle. That fixes the problem.