# 404 file not found when reloading an angular SPA published on github page

Tags: angular, nginx, github, github-pages, ng-build

I am recieving error when reloading my angular application published on gh pages. The error is:

```
404
File not found.
The site configured at this address does not contain the requested file.
```

I have built my app using ng build --prod.

**Github repo:** https://github.com/chirag299051/IceAndFire

**Github page:** https://chirag299051.github.io/IceAndFire/

My app.module.ts file contains:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';

import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { BookDetailsComponent } from './book-details/book- 
details.component';
import { CharDetailsComponent } from './char-details/char- 
details.component';
import { HouseDetailsComponent } from './house-details/house- 
details.component';
import { GotService } from './got.service';
import { GotHttpService } from './got-http.service';

import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
HomeComponent,
AboutComponent,
BookDetailsComponent,
CharDetailsComponent,
HouseDetailsComponent
],
imports: [
HttpClientModule,
BrowserModule,
RouterModule.forRoot([
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path:'',redirectTo:'home',pathMatch:'full'},
  {path: 'about', component: AboutComponent},
  {path: 'book/:name',component : BookDetailsComponent},
  {path: 'char/:url',component : CharDetailsComponent},
  {path: 'house/:name',component : HouseDetailsComponent}
])
],
providers: [GotService,GotHttpService,HttpClient],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And on my subdomain my routes are not working when i click on any links, i have deployed using nginx.

Subdomain : [got.chirag9.com](http://got.chirag9.com)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35038155/how-to-redirect-all-angular-request-to-index-html-in-nginx

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml

Comment: i have already used location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
But reloading problem is on github page not subdomain.

Comment: In subdomain the problem is routes are not working, check the links i provided

Comment: Click the link I posted. It tells you that the only way to have routes working (without using the hash strategy) on github pages is to define a 404 page. nginx is completely irrelevant: github pages doesn't use nginx, and even if it does, you can't alter its configuration.

Answer (score 7):

In app-routing.module.ts file use

```
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{ useHash: true })]
```

instead of

```
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)]
```

Here we have to pass `useHash: true` to enable hash character in URL. This option will help to prevent the reload issue in GitHub pages.