# React Routes not working on Server but work locally

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I can go to the site index www.mysite.com and from there use the app navigation to go to www.mysite.com/login but I can't go directly to www.mysite.com/login as it gives a 404 message.

However this is working in localhost, where I can go straight to https://localhost:3000/login and it will load up the app with the login page route.

How can I get this to work on my Nginx server as-well?

Comment: You need to redirect all requests to index.html. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35038155/how-to-redirect-all-angular-request-to-index-html-in-nginx) for server configuration or you could redirect using server side like node or whatever server side you are using.

Comment: Thanks, add this as an answer and I will mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redirect all requests to index.html.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35038155/how-to-redirect-all-angular-request-to-index-html-in-nginx) for server configuration or you could redirect using server side like node or whatever server side you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your server.js file

```
app.use("/users", require("./routes/users")); app.use("/groups", require("./routes/groups")); app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/client/build")); app.get("/*", (req, res) => { res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html")); });
```