# ReactPDF renderToFile not rendering arabic text

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-pdf, react-pdfrenderer

I'm trying to render PDF to file but the arabic text in the PDF displays as some encoded text like `*BFJ) 'DE9DHE'*`, `1'4/ 'D9H6J`, `*0C1) EF`, etc..

```
-- API --


import { renderToFile } from '@react-pdf/renderer';
import TicketDownloadPDF from '@/sections/@dashboard/ticket/view/TicketDownloadPDF';


export async function handler(req: NextApiReq, res: NextApiResponse) {
  try {
    const { selected } = req.body;

    const selectedTickets = await tickets.find({ _id: { $in: selected } })

    await renderToFile(<TicketDownloadPDF ticket={selectedTickets[0]} />, 'file1.pdf');

    res.status(200).json({ message: 'weewuu' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error' });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register Arabic font separately in your code, but first install `fontkit` module to be able to upload custom fonts:

To do this, use the command: `npm install @react-pdf/fontkit`

Then add registration of your previously downloaded font in the code:

```
import { renderToFile } from '@react-pdf/renderer';
import { Font } from '@react-pdf/renderer';
import path from 'path';
import TicketDownloadPDF from '@/sections/@dashboard/ticket/view/TicketDownloadPDF';

const fontPath = path.resolve('/fonts/ArabicFont.ttf'); // Set you own path here

Font.register({
  family: 'ArabicFont',
  src: fontPath,
});

export async function handler(req, res) {
  try {
    const { selected } = req.body;
    const selectedTickets = await tickets.find({ _id: { $in: selected } });

    await renderToFile(<TicketDownloadPDF ticket={selectedTickets[0]} />, 'file1.pdf');

    res.status(200).json({ message: 'weewuu' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error' });
  }
}
```

Now you should be able to see Arabic symbols properly in a rendered file.
However you should keep in mind that Arabic letters are directed right to left. This can be supported by creating a StyleSheet object with `writingMode` parameter set to `rl` and reuse it as a style for `TicketDownloadPDF`.

If you feel any unclarity or concerns, please let me know.

Comment: where are we using `@react-pdf/fontkit` module

Comment: I'm getting `[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/rashidalawadhi/Code/SSC Projects/ticketing-system/.next/server/pages/api/section/ticket/fonts/Vazirmatn-Regular.ttf']`

Comment: the font is not being added to .next build

Comment: Hmm it's hard to say without seeing your project structure. Try adding the font file to public/fonts directory and update the paths respectively. Then rebuild your project.

Comment: adding the font to public/font only works when I render pdf on cilent-side, because `src: '/fonts/ArabicFont.ttf'` would point to the file in public folder. but it doesnt work that way when rendering on serverside, cause its trying to point to file path location

Comment: its working when I do `src: 'http://localhost:8081/fonts/ArabicFont.ttf'`

Comment: Make sure that fonts folder is added to your paths (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58091542/15952589), or probably this is the issue with your project configuration in general, I'm not sure. Did you succeed in rendering Arabic symbols locally?

Comment: this problem is occurring locally

Comment: how can I add fonts folder to next.js paths? the post you referenced is for express