# Server returns 404 not found for Angular query parameters (e.g.: example.com/queryparam)

Tags: angular, nginx

On localhost:

`localhost:4200/1229` where `1229` is the query's parameter in Routes `path: ':id'`

This works on local, but when deployed into the server,

`server_url/1229` returns 404 Not found nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

I think currently your webserver is handling routes but you need to Config your webserver (here Nginx) to redirect all routes and 404 to your index in order to handle by Angular router.
you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35038155/how-to-redirect-all-angular-request-to-index-html-in-nginx)