# Accessing an Angular route in Nginx returns 404 Not Found

Tags: angular, nginx, angular-routing, angular-router, nginx-location

Accessing/refresh a route directly in the browser like **/login** or **/signup** returns 404 Not Found.

I build the project and hosted the static files in the **/html** folder on the Nginx server. The server understands that the route is a folder, but it really isn't. Should I change something in the code block in Nginx, like **location / {...}** or something in Angular?

Comment: Nginx should always serve `index.html`, on any route. And then Angular will take care of routing. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35038155/how-to-redirect-all-angular-request-to-index-html-in-nginx