# How to redirect url with parameters in nginx

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

for example, i want to redirect from https://www.example.com/${pid}.txt to http://www.anotherExample.com/api?pid=${pid}
how to configure it in nginx?
Thanks in advance:)

Comment: see this http://lethain.com/rewriting-parameterized-urls-with-nginx/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect a url in NGINX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294481/how-to-redirect-a-url-in-nginx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
server {

  listen 443;
  server_name www.example.com;

  location ~* ^/(.+)\.txt$ {
    return 301 http://www.anotherexample.com/api?pid=$1;
  }

}
```

If your `pid` have a specific format (only digits for example) then replace `(.+)` with appropriate pattern.

If you want to display content without redirecting then replace `return 301` with `proxy_pass`.

Comment: i use  location ~ ^/([^/.]*).txt$ {
    return 301 http://www.anotherexample.com/api?pid=$1;
  }  but it say 502 errors, and can't find anything useful in error.log, any idea?

Comment: @NingLv tested - regexp works fine in my environment. Did you added https params? Try first on `http://` with `listen 80;`.

Comment: @NingLv also you can try escaping backslashes: `\/` instead of `/`. This depends on nginx version

Comment: @NingLv pls let me know when you'll get working config. Or just update this answer. This can be helpful for somebody else

Comment: for comparation, just use server {

  listen 443;
  server_name www.anotherexample.com;

  location ~ ^/([^/.]*).txt$ {
    proxy_pass http://www.anotherexample.com/api?pid=$1;
  }

} and still can get a 502 error， and if i don't use regex, location /123.txt {
    proxy_pass http://www.anotherexample.com/api?pid=123;
  } and it works fine, and i change another regex expression, still not work. so confused... why regex not working on my nginx?

Comment: @NingLv tell me the version of your nginx and your os name

Comment: @ Maxim Korshunov  nginx version: nginx/1.5.6  , os version:centos 4.3

Comment: @NingLv I use nginx v1.10. The answer updated: regexp simplified, added . escaping before `txt` (this was mistake), and `~` to `~*`, try now.

Answer (score 1):

the best way is with a `return 301`, it will redirect the request to the site you are setting to, perhaps it will be better make a `return 301 $scheme://www.anotherexample.com/api?pid=$1;`, in this way your URL will be redirected as a HTTPS when you purchase and install an SSL

Comment: i use  location ~ ^/([^/.]*).txt$ {
    return 301 http://www.anotherexample.com/api?pid=$1;
  }  but it say 502 errors, and can't find anything useful in error.log, any idea?