# Make Nginx redirect http://example.com/profile to http://example.com/#/profile (angular route)?

Tags: angularjs, nginx, server, routes

Forcing html5 in angular is not an option since I need users to be able to use the website regardless of the browser they use. Any request with the same format should get redirected to its angular route.

Comment: could use a haproxy solution too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect a url in NGINX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294481/how-to-redirect-a-url-in-nginx)

Comment: Just add a rule to nginx that when any request to `http://example.com/*` is made, nginx has to serve `http://example.com/index.html`. AngularJS will take care of the rest.

Comment: @georgeawg mind adding an example? can't find any similar ones

Comment: See [Module ngx_http_rewrite_module Documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html).